# Good PyQt tutorial needed

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I'm starting getting into `PyQt`. Therefore I would need some good tutorials. I searched a bit but didn't find any good. Most tutorials only post "full" applications but don't go into detail.

Can you advise me some?

Currently im programming in `Notepad++`. Are there better lightweight editors or simple IDEs for python in combination with PyQt?

Comment: sublime text is good IDE.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should probably ask two different questions here, one regarding the PyQt tutorial and one about a better editor. Also both could be more precise (PyQt version, editor expectations and so on)

However here's where you could start:

PyQt4:

1. read about Qt at nokia.com and bookmark the documentation: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/gettingstartedqt.html
2. bookmark the PyQt documentation: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/
3. think about getting this book: http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html
4. do this tutorial: http://wiki.python.org/moin/JonathanGardnerPyQtTutorial
5. define a simple project you want to start with and do it with all the resources you have now

Editor:

1. think about getting this book: http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer
2. install emacs, vim and eclipse+pydev
3. spend some time (>3h) for learning and trying those environments
4. decide what works best for you / or could work best for you (it takes a bit longer than 3h to get up to speed in emacs or vi)
5. improve your environment every day

I hope this helps to get you started. It is just a proposal,.. there are many ways to Rome...

Comment: I have been using Qt for years, so it is easy for me to use PyQt. Actually I wonder if there's possibility to jump to use PyQt without knowledge of Qt itself.

Comment: The link http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/ is broken with a 404 error page

Answer (score 7):

[**"The PyQt4 tutorial"**](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/) by Jan Bodnar ([ZetCode](http://zetcode.com/))

Answer (score 3):

This [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/) helped me very well.

> Currently I'm programming in Notepad++. Are there better lightweight
>   editors or simple IDEs for Python in combination with PyQt?

[Qt creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) works fine with Python, you can also draw the interface with drag and drop..

Answer (score 2):

As novalis mentions, the nokia api docs on Qt are great, but you were looking for tutorials on PyQt specifically.

There's a quick list [at the python.org page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) which includes a few tutorial links.

The [zetcode tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/) also has some followers, but be a bit careful with the rather manual process of gui creation.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ docs for QT are actually a pretty good reference for PyQT.  Last time I used PyQT (> 5 years ago), they were actually the best available reference.